# What is a "partitioned view"?

Tags: oracle, view, terminology

What is a "partitioned view"? I googled but could not get a satisfactory result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Partitioned views are a (very) old technique for partitioning data that are very rarely used today.  Oracle added the ability to partition tables back in Oracle 8, which provides much more functionality than partitioned views, at which point partitioned views became obsolete.  The only reason to consider using partitioned views would be if you can't afford a license for the partitioning option and you're willing to accept the reduced functionality and extra maintenance required to use partitioned views.  The documentation on [partitioned views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/A48506/partview.htm) will pretty much all date back to the Oracle 7 days.

In order to use partitioned views, you would define individual tables for each logical partition, create a `CHECK` constraint on whatever column you want to partition on so that the optimizer knows which table a particular row must be in, and then create a view that does a `UNION ALL` on each table to create the partitioned view.  Queries against the partitioned view using the partition key can then be resolved by the optimizer to access only one of the physical tables comprising a particular logical partition.

Of course, if you use this technique, you have to create a new physical table and rebuild the partitioned view every time you add a new partition which is quite a bit of maintenance.  Getting the partitioned view to work correctly and making sure that partition pruning is happening correctly is much, much more challenging than when you're using a partitioned table.  Plus you end up with a ton of separate tables with very similar names polluting your namespace.

Comment: Might have been worth mentioning INSTEAD OF INSERT triggers on views, though

Comment: _"..create a CHECK constraint on whatever column you want to partition on so that the optimizer knows which table a particular row must be in, and then create a view that does a UNION ALL on each table to create the partitioned view."_ I didn't quite understand this. Will you please simplify a bit

Comment: +1: However they do have the advantages of allowing different storage and indexing options per "partition", and allowing more flexible execution plans (eg. index-based lookup on some partitions, elimination of others, full scan of others). Considering the enormous cost of an upgrade to Enterprise Edition *and* the Partitioning Option, I'd consider them if I was using Standard Edition. The extra work is manageable.

Comment: @SuhailGupta - The documentation I linked to walks through a complete example.  That is probably easier to follow than any summary I could come up with.

Comment: I think Oracle de-supported Partitioned Views in O9iR2. Certainly there's no PARTITION_VIEW_ENABLED in 11gR2.